# Delete a field from Firestore, with a variable key

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete field by dynamic variable
I tried to put the variable in `[]` like this:

```js
var removeCapital = cityRef.update({
    [variable]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
});
```

but it didn't work. Any other solutions, please?
I think the problem is from the structure of the key it is like
'0.maze.1.1' because when I tried the same method with key 'test' it worked.

Comment: Please could you provide more detail that "it didn't work"? What happened, precisely?

Comment: I think the problem is from the structure of the key it is like '0.maze.1.1' because when I tried the same method with key 'test' it worked.